# How to check if some values of a dict is in nested dict and return location?

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I have a nested dict with the following values:

```
 bcs = {'L_1':{'Side':'l','Type':'c', 'T':''} , 'L_2':{'Side':'s','Type':'c', 'T':''}}
 bps = {'L_1':{'Side':'l','Type':'p', 'T':''}, 'L_2':{'Side':'s','Type':'p', 'T':''}}
 mA = {'BC':bcs,'BP':bps}
```

I have a 'vector' with data:

```
vData = {'Side':'s','Type':'c', 'T':120}
```

I want to check if the values of 'Side' and 'Type' of vData is in mA and where they are.

So for example, we know that vData exists for those values in mA['bcs']['L_2']. I then want to store the location, that is: **['bcs']['L_2']** in a list or somewhere. It is possible that there are more hits in the 'matrix' mA.

How do I solve this problem? I also tried converting it to binary or numerical values (a mapping function if you like) to create a search space but not sure how to continue with that.

EDIT:

Input:

```
vData = {'Side':'s','Type':'c', 'T':120}
```

Output:

```
Location = ['bcs']['L_2']
```

Because:

**bcs** = {'L_1':{'Side':'l','Type':'c', 'T':''} , '**L_2**':{'Side':'**s**','Type':'**c**', 'T':''}}

Comment: Ok, I've read this question like three times and I still don't get what you're asking for.  Are you saying you want a function `get_address(vData, bcs) == 'L_2'` and `get_address(vData, bps) == 'L_2'`?  Or something else?  It would be helpful if you put the expected input/output behavior of the desired functionality in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
result = [
    (k1, k2) 
    for k1, d in mA.items() 
    for k2, v in d.items() 
    if v['Side'] == vData['Side'] and v['Type'] == vData['Type']
]
```

Result:

```
[('BC', 'L_2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
for (x,y) in vData.items():
    for (mA1,mA2) in mA.items():
        for (search1,search2)in mA2.items() :
            if (x,y) in search2.items():
                print("found '{}':'{}'".format(x,y))
```

hope that this is the answer you are looking for .